# Calculate Velocity TYPE_COUNTER_STEP SENSOR

Tags: java, android

I am very close to finish my project that is related to count steps , distance covered and calculate velocity. I am using TYPE_COUNTER_STEP sensor to calculate the steps and using formulas to calculate distance i.e 0.415 for men and 0.413 for women to get foot length by multiplying with height So far every thing is working fine But i am suck to calculate the velocity. I do not know how to calculate, i mean i know s = vt but i need time to get the velocity/step. Anyone have any idea how to achieve that. This is the last part of my project. I have also look for it on the internet but i did not get working method to calculate the time. Someone suggest me to use timestamp but i used that but unfortunately i get infinity text instead of velocity

I cannot use GPS to calculate the velocity because GPS is not available all the time i.e inside tunnel or underground etc
Thanks

```
package com.lijianzhong13354146.coeur1;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AccurateStepCounter extends AppCompatActivity {

    private long timestamp;

    private TextView textViewStepCounter;

    private TextView textViewStepDetector;

    private Thread detectorTimeStampUpdaterThread;

    private Handler handler;
    Toolbar toolbar ;
    private Button buttonStop ;
    TextView stepValue ;
    TextView distanceValue ;
    TextView distanceTitle ;

    int getCurrentStepValue ;
    int actualStepTaken ;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor ;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFromSetting ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorFromSetting ;
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    ArrayList<Step> arrayList ;
    String gettingPersonHeight ;
    double gettingPersonHeightInDoule ;
    double step_length ;
SharedPreferences getSharedPreferencesHeight ;
SharedPreferences.Editor getEditoHeight ;
    double timeInSecond    ;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesGetGender ;
SharedPreferences.Editor editorGetGender;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accurate_step_counter);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSTOP);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        stepValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.step_value);
        distanceValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_value);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("saveInformation" , MODE_PRIVATE) ;
        sharedPreferencesFromSetting = getSharedPreferences("EmailSave" , MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferencesGetGender = getSharedPreferences("saveInformation" , MODE_PRIVATE);
   getSharedPreferencesHeight = getSharedPreferences("Height" , MODE_PRIVATE);

        distanceTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_title);



        gettingPersonHeightInDoule = Double.parseDouble(
                getSharedPreferencesHeight.getString("saveHeight" , "0"))/100;

        if (sharedPreferencesGetGender.getString("GENDER" , null).equals("Male") ){

            step_length = 0.415 * gettingPersonHeightInDoule ;

        }else {
            step_length = 0.413 * gettingPersonHeightInDoule ;

        }



        ToolbarConfig();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.boom);
        mediaPlayer1.start();

        registerForSensorEvents();
        onStopButtonClick();












        //  setupDetectorTimestampUpdaterThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    public void onStopButtonClick () {


        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int actualSteps = getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0);

                editor = sharedPreferences.edit() ;
                editor.putString("STEPS" , String.valueOf(actualSteps));

                editor.commit() ;






               startActivity(new Intent(AccurateStepCounter.this , FinalResultDisplay.class));

            }
        });

    }
    public void  ToolbarConfig () {
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_title));

        toolbar.setSubtitle("Pedometer");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    }

    public void registerForSensorEvents() {
        SensorManager sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Step Counter
        sManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {

                                      @Override
                                      public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {



                                          Step step = new Step(event.values[0], System.currentTimeMillis());

                                          arrayList.add(step);
                                          getCurrentStepValue = (int) step.getStep();

                                          stepValue.setText(getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0) + "");

                                          double distaneCovered = step_length * (getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0));

                                          // the elapsed time beetween 2 step will be:
                                          if (arrayList.size() > 2) {
                                              Step lastStep = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);
                                              Step previousStep = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 2);
                                              long msElapsedTime = lastStep.getTimestamp() - previousStep.getTimestamp();

                                              timeInSecond = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(msElapsedTime);


                                          }

                                          double getVelocity = distaneCovered / timeInSecond ;


                                          // distanceTitle shows the speed for now
                                            distanceTitle.setText(getVelocity + " m/s");
                                          distanceValue.setText("" + distaneCovered);








                                        /*  float steps = event.values[0];

                                          arrayList.add((int)steps);
                                          getCurrentStepValue = (int) steps ;


                                          double distanceCovered = (step_length * (getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0))) /1000;


                                          stepValue.setText(getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0) + "");
                                          distanceValue.setText("" + String.format("%.2f" , distanceCovered));*/


                                      }

                                      @Override
                                      public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

                                      }
                                  }, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
}

  class Step {
    private float step;
    private long timestamp;



      Step (float step , long timestamp) {

          this.step = step;
          this.timestamp = timestamp ;

      }

      public void setStep(float step) {
          this.step = step;
      }

      public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
          this.timestamp = timestamp;
      }

      public float getStep() {
          return step;
      }

      public long getTimestamp() {
          return timestamp;
      }
      // getters

    // setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the elapsed time beetween 2 steps creating a Step class containing the timestamp as field. Then subtract the previous timestamp at the last!

```
public class Step {
    private float step;
    private long timestamp;

    // constructor

    // getters

    // setters
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Step step = new Step(event.values[0], System.currentTimeMillis());

    arrayList.add(step);
    getCurrentStepValue = (int) step.getStep();
    stepValue.setText(getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0) + "");

    double distaneCovered = step_length * (getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0));

    // the elapsed time beetween 2 step will be:
    if (arrayList.size() > 2) {
        Step lastStep = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);
        Step previousStep = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 2);
        long msElapsedTime = lastStep.getTimestamp() - previousStep.getTimestamp(); 
    }

    distanceValue.setText("" + distaneCovered);
}
```

So you can do s=v/t

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i am still getting infinity .. If i take step with some time i get velocity of 10 or 14 or 5 m/s but if i move like normal i get infinity